# Android DarkMode Strategy selection does not work with Cordova (prefers-color-scheme)

Tags: android, cordova, webview, cordovawebview

I am using Cordova for Android App. I load a webpage on CordovaWebView which has dark mode css defined as @media(prefers-color-scheme). Android does not respect the Webpage Dark Scheme. (`<head> has <meta name="color-scheme" content="dark light">`)

There are two stategy of DarkMode that Android supports.

- Color-Inversion (DARK_STRATEGY_USER_AGENT_DARKENING_ONLY)
- Webpage scheme  (DARK_STRATEGY_WEB_THEME_DARKENING_ONLY)

And Android lets you [decide the dark mode strategy](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/dark-theme#customize) using this code

```
 if (WebViewFeature.isFeatureSupported(WebViewFeature.FORCE_DARK_STRATEGY)) {
        WebSettingsCompat.setForceDarkStrategy(webView.getSettings(), WebSettingsCompat.DARK_STRATEGY_WEB_THEME_DARKENING_ONLY);
 }
```

But it does not seem to work with Cordova WebView. (I tested this code with WebView. It works fine).

What am I missing here? Is this a Cordova Bug? I found something on [Cordova Github Bug Report](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/issues/897) . But I did not find any solution.

Comment: What is "not working"? You don't say what you're trying to achieve. Dark Mode works fine using Cordova in my Ionic 4/5/6 Apps. Why you need to change "strategy" if the default one works well by detecting Mode by itselfs?

Comment: Because By default Android does color inversion on Webpage Content. And I have a dedicated Dark theme for Webpage. That Is why I need to change the "strategy" . Do you use @media(prefers-color-scheme) in your css? @emandt

Comment: Sure, a ":root" and a "@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark)" section in my "variables.scss". The first one is used as Base and for Light version, and the Dark variables are used when DarkMode is active.

Comment: So do you have a custom Theme (styles.xml) for Android ? I don't know why it does not work. WebSettingsCompat.setForceDark(webView.getSettings(), FORCE_DARK_OFF) works fine but not the .setForceDarkStrategy

Comment: I am assuming the problem with CordovaWebView because the dark scheme for webpage seems to work with iOS devices.

Comment: The App is rendered by a WebView, so all Styles and CSS are not present in "style.xml" like a Native App....infact I don't have any XML file for style.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243249/discussion-between-rohit-singh-and-emandt).

Answer (score 0):

I made an example project at https://github.com/hanscappelle/android-darkmode-example after having to fix similar issues. This is what I did to support dark mode + let a user change modes in app.

## Use a theme with support for Dark mode

The first step is to use a theme that fully supports dark mode for your app. You typically start from a base theme, those with `Light` in the name are specific light themes that will require more steps to get this working (see later). For now pick a theme with `DayNight` in the name as a parent for your app theme.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
```

More on dark mode supported themes https://m2.material.io/develop/android/theming/dark

If you're looking for the needed dependency for the above theme:

```
implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0")
```

## Check that your web content supports dark mode

For the web content to support dark mode you'll need this css:

```
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark)
```

A full html example is available in the project also in the `webapp` folder. You can also use this example app hosted at firebase for a quick test https://darkmode-example.web.app/

## Optionally allow user to select Mode

With above steps you should already have your app and webview render content in dark or light mode depending on your system settings on the device.

In order to allow the user to overrule this setting for your app you'll need to provide some setting that triggers this (for API level 31 and above):

```
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
    private fun forceMode(mode: int) {
        val uiManager = getSystemService(UI_MODE_SERVICE) as UiModeManager
        uiManager.setApplicationNightMode(mode)
    }
```

Note that `UiModeManager.MODE_NIGHT_NO`mode will force the use of light mode. Dark mode is forced with `UiModeManager.MODE_NIGHT_YES`and `UiModeManager.MODE_NIGHT_AUTO` uses the system wide theme again.

The example project contains code for lower API levels (<=30) also where the `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode` method is used instead. Plus different modes! So double check imports.

## Optionally stick to `Light` base theme

If you want to stick to light theme for some reason there are also options to force dark mode on that, but by default it will handle everything as a light theme even if the system is set to dark.

More info on how to work that out https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/theming/darktheme#force-dark